# How to find a drone that has not made its way back to my ship

Tags: x-rebirth

I need to use my hacker drone, however when I go to the drone menu it says docking in progress. I have not used the drone for a few hours of game time. Is it slowly trying to make its way to me? If so can I locate it somehow and fly back to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-game way to select or find your drone.

You should sell it and replace it with new one.

Actually my undocked drones dissapeared from drone menu when I entered highway.

You can search your savefile for drone entry, locate zone and then fly to it, but savefile is 30-50 Mb of XML.

Comment: Thanks, would you happen to know what the XML node for the drone location would look like? That way I can just write an application to find it if notepad is going to struggle to open it.Am I able to sell the drone even if it is lost?

Comment: Try to search for "unit_player_hacker_drone_macro", not sure how it will be represented in savefile. Try to sell it and see if it will work.